# Troubleshooting discord bot in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

i have tried to work with tutorials on how to create a discord bot for my server. It works fine until it gets to the part where the bot is supposed to respond to messages. There is simply no response, yet the bot is online. Can anyone figure out why?

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'MY TOKEN'

INTENT = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=INTENT)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == 'hi':
        response = "hello"
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: To those who say I should e.g use intents.all() ... that doesnt work either. In fact I get more error messages when I do so.

Comment: Due to a new Discord API update, you need to enable [message content intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content)

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you need to enable [Intents.message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content) so that your bot can read the content of messages.
Furthermore, I recommend you to use the [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html) framework to develop your bot better:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True   # This is required to use text commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.command
async def hello(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.reply(f"Hi {ctx.author.name}!")


bot.run('MY TOKEN')
```

To trigger the command just use `!hello`. The bot will respond to your message by saying `Hi Hazzu`!

> Note: you need to enable privileged gateway intent message content in the developer portal.